# Horizontal CSS Alignment

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain how I keep my buttons positioned in the center of the red area, no matter the width of the buttons?

Here is my **Demo**:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3X2k/

And here is my code:

```
<div style="width:660px;height:40px;display;block;background:red">

    <div id="wrapper3" style="margin:0 auto;width:160px">

        <button>Test</button>
        <button>Test 2</button>

    </div>

</div>

<hr />

<div style="width:660px;height:40px;display;block;background:red">

    <div id="wrapper3" style="margin:0 auto;width:160px">

        <button>Test Test Test Test Test Test</button>
        <button>Test 2</button>

    </div>

</div>
```

You can see in the 2nd example, the 2nd button drops below, when actually I would like them to remain inline, like the ones above.

I'm happy to drop the `width:160px` statement, but just need to align these buttons centrally.

Any ideas?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use a wrapper div with fixed width and margin auto...just use `text-align: center;` on container div

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3X2k/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
text-align: center;
```

Buttons are inline elements, so this will work.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3X2k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Some people call it bad practice and I guess you do have to be careful but you can use:

`<center></center>`